# Building a matrix in python

Tags: python, list, text, matrix

Python beginner here.
I have two text files with the same format of tab-delimited information. They contain rows with 3 columns (identifier, chromosome and position) eg:

File 1:

```
2323 2 125
2324 3 754
```

... etc

File 2:

```
2323 2 150
2324 3 12000
```

... etc

I want to create a list or matrix (not sure exactly what is best or how this works, maybe a list of lists that becomes a matrix?!) by going through each identifier (the first column in each row) in one file and associate it with its position (column3), then find this matching identifier in the next file and also save the other position (column3) in this file. SO in the end each identifier will be associated with 2 different positions from the two different files.

This is what I need help with. For the next step I will look for identifiers with the largest numerical difference between positions.

Any help, tips or solutions are greatly appreciated, I am a python beginner with a very basic knowledge.

Many thanks in advance!

Rubal

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to construct using the two values you get in column 3 of the two files. Can you clarify what the desired output is? Is it result something you want to write back into one of the files, or something you'll be using for further processing?

Answer (score 2):

There can be several answers to your question:

1. If you plan to use extensive computations with matrices, I advice you to look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/) library  that is very efficient. You can see how to create matrices with numpy [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).
2. The second possible answer to your question is to use [biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) library (I've made conclusion about that you're working with chromosomes).
3. You can use Python nested lists to create matrices.

Here's a code snippet of how to do that (assuming we're reading from File 2)

```
matrix = []
with open(path_to_file2, 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        matrix.append(map(int, line.strip().split(' ')))
```

You can then get values of the created matrix:

```
matrix[0]     # First row == [2323, 2, 150]
matrix[0][1]  # Second column, first row == 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections
d=collections.defaultdict(list)
for f in ('file1','file2'):
    with open(f) as f1:
        for line in f1:
            ident, chrom, pos = line.split()
            d[ident].append(int( pos ))


#big differences at end of list
items = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda item: abs(item[1][1] - item[1][0])) 

#big differences at beginning of list
#items = sorted(d.items(), reverse = True, key = lambda item: abs(item[1][1] - item[1][0]))
```

In this solution, I store the information from the files as a dictionary.  the keys are the identifier and the values are a list containing the positions.  I then sort the items of that dictionary based on the absolute value of the difference between the first and second element in the list of positions.  In other words, the biggest differences are at the end of the `items` list.

In order for this to work, it assumes that `file1` and `file2` have *the same identifiers*.  If they don't, you'll first need to filter the items to pick out only dictionary entries with values that have a length of 2.  e.g.

```
items = [(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if len(v) == 2]
items = sorted(items, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary having the identifier as the key and a list of the positions as the value. Then you can calculate the difference between the positions and have it as the 3rd element of the list. You can then iterate through the dictionary finding the largest value in position [2] of the dictionary's values.

```
d = {}
for each line in file1:
   d[identifier] = [position]

for each line in file2:
   d[identifier].append(position)
   d[identifier].append(d[identifier][1]-d[identifier][0])

maxDiff = 0
for x in d:
    value = d[x][2]
    if value > maxDiff:
        maxDiff = value
```